# yql : Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL

Tags: java, yql

If i do it from the Front End the following is working fine

```
  var symbol = symbolsarray[i].trim();
  var query = "select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol = " + "'" + symbol + "'";
  var yql = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" + escape(query) + "&format=json&diagnostics=false&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=?";
```

I have tried it to do the same from java this way

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class JSONfunctions {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        getQuote();
    }

    private static Double getQuote() {
        try {
            // URL url = new
            // URL("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%27%255EHSI%27&format=json&diagnostics=false&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=jQuery1830024542473256587982_1445857302444");

            String symbol = "%5EAORD";
            String query = "select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol = "
                    + "'" + symbol + "'";

            String yql = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q="
                    + query
                    + "&format=json&diagnostics=false&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=?";

            URL url = new URL(yql);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    url.openStream()));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

But i am getting response as

```
Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol = '%5EAORD'&format=json&diagnostics=false&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode your query for use in a url.

```
String yql = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q="
                + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8")
                + "&format=json&diagnostics=false&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=?";
```

Your query contains spaces so i suspect that this might be a solution.

Comment: Thank you now i am getting /**/yql_invalid_callback({"error":{"lang":"en-US","description":"Invalid JSON callback parameter yql_invalid_callback"}});

Comment: Take a look at the parameter ``callback``. You are sending the value "?" which is not correct. That's exactly what the error message is telling you.

Comment: I am getting this same error. This query always had callback set to "?" but has seemed to quit working overnight.

Comment: It turns out my issue was because Yahoo's service was down.